# Do default constructors need to call base class default constructors?

Tags: c++, constructor

Was reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3217473/768472) and it surprised me, the suggestion you must *always* call a base class constructor in the derived class constructor. What if you are working only with default constructors, consider:

```
class Bar : public Foo {
private:
int y;

public:
Bar() : Foo(), y(0) {
}

...
```

Is the call to `Foo()` really necessary here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to *explicitly* call a base class constructor in your constructor, in which case the compiler *implicitly* calls the default constructor, or you get a compile-time error, if none is callable.
Same applies to members who are non-POD.

An alternative is a member initialiser list **only** consisting of a delegation to another constructor of your class, thus creating a delegating constructor.

Answer (score 2):

No, you don't. The reason why this is done is readability. It's clearer to read and might hint some IDEs helper logic like where the Baseclass::Baseclass() method is used.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to call them but I think it is a good idea in terms of readabilitty and also proves to the person reviewing the code that you understand that the class is derived.